How to deduce whether a classmethod is called on an instance or on a class
I'm writing a logger decorator that can be applied to, among others, classmethods (and theoretically any kind of function or method). My problem is that their parametrization changes according to whether a function is

a standalone_function(*args)
a member_method(self, *args) or
a class_method(cls, *args)

An example code that works but all but elegant and can be tricked by parametrization:
def some_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*argsWrap, **kwargsWrap):
        if isinstance(func, classmethod):
            if isinstance(argsWrap[0], SomeClass):
                # Called by some_instance.some_method as the first parameter is SomeClass 
                print(argsWrap[1])
                return func.__func__(*argsWrap, **kwargsWrap)
            else:
                # Called by SomeClass.some_method
                print(argsWrap[0])
                return func.__func__(SomeClass, *argsWrap, **kwargsWrap)
        else:
            return func(*argsWrap, **kwargsWrap)
    return wrapper


class SomeClass:
    @some_decorator
    @classmethod
    def some_method(cls, some_var: str):
        print(some_var)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SomeClass.some_method('Test')
    some_instance = SomeClass()
    some_instance.some_method('Test2')

Question is simple: is it possible to make a cleaner and safer decision regarding just the parametrization?
Note that for a general purpose decorator (used by others) one cannot say that this must be put below the @classmethod, not above etc.
Also note that this solution is a "bad" workaround in a sense that one can conveniently imagine functions that use more instances of the same class (for example, a typical overloaded operator, like __eq__ works like this).
Also note that the real problem, as I narrowed it, is that a classmethod called upon a class or called upon an instance of a class passes different parametrization (the first parameter being the first arg for a class-bound function and the class reference for an instance-bound function).

actually, if it is meant to work both with plain functions, methods and classmethods, it is pretty reasonable to require that in combination with class methods it should be put either "above" or "bellow" @classmethod, and not "either way goes". Just document it correctly. But, yes, it can be made to work they way you are planning,

fThe expected functionality is to write a function by "user", let it be a @classmethod or anything else AND THEN, if needed, put my decorator to do the logging. So because of the expected workflow it's very rational my decorator to be the outer/upper one logging anything that is inside (let it be any number/kind of decorators, including the @classmethod)

I use class decorator, __call__ and __get__ to do the trick.
Here it is:
class LoggerDecorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self.func.__get__(owner, owner)
        return self.func.__get__(instance, owner)


Explainations:
The key idea behind this implementation is to use the __get__ and __call__ methods within a class decorator to handle different types of function call.
The problem we are facing here is that the decorator is used as a generic way to wrap various functions, but the parameters it receives vary depending on the type of function being called (e.g., classmethod(cls, ), staticmethod(), instance method(self, )). As the author of the topic mentioned, parametrization(e.g. using the type of  function's first parameter) as the determining condition for the wrapper function is undoubtedly risky.
Here, instead of using a function decorator, we use a class decorator. The condition for handling the decorator is shifted from the 'parametrization' of a wrapper helper function to the __get__ descriptor, which determines whether the function is being used by an instantiated instance.

__get__ : The __get__ method is called to get the attribute of the owner class (class attribute access) or of an instance of that class (instance attribute access).
Let’s take a "classmethod" as an example and compare the differences in the get method when it's called 'directly' (normal usage) versus when it's called by an instantiated instance:
class LoggerDecorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print(f'self:     {self}')
        print(f'instance: {instance}')
        print(f'owner:    {owner}')
        return self.func.__get__(owner, owner)

 class SomeClass:
     @LoggerDecorator
     @classmethod
     def class_method(cls, some_var):
         print(f"print some_var: {some_var}")

# Call Directly
SomeClass.class_method("Call Directly")

# Called by instance.
s = SomeClass()
s.class_method("Called by instance")

# OUTPUT
--- Called by directly ---
self:     <__main__.LoggerDecorator object at 0x7f36aad05590>
instance: None
owner:    <class '__main__.SomeClass'>
print some_var: Call Directly

--- Called by instance ---
self:     <__main__.LoggerDecorator object at 0x7f36aad05590>
instance: <__main__.SomeClass object at 0x7f36aad06150>
owner:    <class '__main__.SomeClass'>
print some_var: Called by instance

We can observe that if called directly, the instance will be None. And the result is the same for a static method (an instance is needed to call it). Therefore, we can use whether the instance in __get__ is None as a determining factor.

__call__: The __call__ method is responsible for handling the decoration of "standalone functions" or any function that does not belong to a class. When we decorate a function like this:
@LoggerDecorator
def standalone_function():
   return

which is equal to
LoggerDecorator(standalone_function)

and this triggers the __call__ method.



Fully Test: Code & Result
class LoggerDecorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
 
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
 
    def __get__(self, instance, owner): 
        print(f'self:     {self}')
        print(f'instance: {instance}')
        print(f'owner:    {owner}')

        if not instance:
            return self.func.__get__(owner, owner)
        return self.func.__get__(instance, owner)


class SomeClass:
    @LoggerDecorator
    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls, some_var: str, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Class method: {some_var}")
        print(f"Class method args: {args}")
        print(f"Class method kwargs: {kwargs}")
    
    @LoggerDecorator
    def instance_method(self, some_var: str, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Instance method: {some_var}")
        print(f"Instance method args: {args}")
        print(f"Instance method kwargs: {kwargs}")

    @LoggerDecorator
    @staticmethod
    def static_method(some_var: str, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Static method: {some_var}")
        print(f"Static method args: {args}")
        print(f"Static method kwargs: {kwargs}")

@LoggerDecorator
def standalone_function(some_var: str, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f"Standalone function: {some_var}")
    print(f"Standalone function args: {args}")
    print(f"Standalone function kwargs: {kwargs}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ### Class Method ###
    # Call Directly
    print("### Class Method ###")
    print("--- Called by directly ---")
    SomeClass.class_method("Test1", "class_directly", a1="class_a", b1="class_b")

    # Called by instance.
    print("")
    print("--- Called by instance ---")
    s = SomeClass()
    s.class_method("Test2", "class_by_instance", a1="class_a", b1="class_b")
 
    ### Static Method ###
    # Call Directly
    print("")
    print("### Static Method ###")
    print("--- Called by directly ---")
    SomeClass.static_method("Test3", "static_directly", a1="static_a", b1="static_b")
 
    # Called by instance.
    print("")
    print("--- Called by instance ---")
    s.static_method("Test4", "static_by_instance", a1="static_a", b1="static_b")
 
    ### Instance Method ###
    # Call only by instance
    print("")
    print("### Instance Method ###")
    s.instance_method("Test5", "instance", a1="instance_a", b1="instance_b")

    ### Standalone Function
    print("")
    print("### Standalone Function ###")
    standalone_function("Test6", "standalone", a1="standalone_a", b1="standalone_b")



### Class Method ###
--- Called by directly ---
self:     <__main__.LoggerDecorator object at 0x7f858c34e390>
instance: None
owner:    <class '__main__.SomeClass'>
Class method: Test1
Class method args: ('class_directly',)
Class method kwargs: {'a1': 'class_a', 'b1': 'class_b'}

--- Called by instance ---
self:     <__main__.LoggerDecorator object at 0x7f858c34e390>
instance: <__main__.SomeClass object at 0x7f858c34f410>
owner:    <class '__main__.SomeClass'>
Class method: Test2
Class method args: ('class_by_instance',)
Class method kwargs: {'a1': 'class_a', 'b1': 'class_b'}

### Static Method ###
--- Called by directly ---
self:     <__main__.LoggerDecorator object at 0x7f858c34f0d0>
instance: None
owner:    <class '__main__.SomeClass'>
Static method: Test3
Static method args: ('static_directly',)
Static method kwargs: {'a1': 'static_a', 'b1': 'static_b'}

--- Called by instance ---
self:     <__main__.LoggerDecorator object at 0x7f858c34f0d0>
instance: <__main__.SomeClass object at 0x7f858c34f410>
owner:    <class '__main__.SomeClass'>
Static method: Test4
Static method args: ('static_by_instance',)
Static method kwargs: {'a1': 'static_a', 'b1': 'static_b'}

### Instance Method ###
self:     <__main__.LoggerDecorator object at 0x7f858c34e510>
instance: <__main__.SomeClass object at 0x7f858c34f410>
owner:    <class '__main__.SomeClass'>
Instance method: Test5
Instance method args: ('instance',)
Instance method kwargs: {'a1': 'instance_a', 'b1': 'instance_b'}

### Standalone Function ###
Standalone function: Test6
Standalone function args: ('standalone',)
Standalone function kwargs: {'a1': 'standalone_a', 'b1': 'standalone_b'}


Good approach, but seems still buggy IMHO. At the first line "SomeClass.class_method", 'cls' argument gets the first argument 'Test1', instead of 'some_variable'. 'cls' should get the class reference instead.

I think it still doesn't work and doesn't seem to catch the distinction between a classmetod called on a class and called on an instance. Check it for SomeClass.class_method("Test1") versus some_instance.class_method("Test2"). In theory both should work and would give back the same result.

Is it working for you now? I slightly changed the log output expression, but then I realized I had done something redundant. lol

Unfortunately not. The approach still cannot make a distinction between the class_method called on a class and called on an instance. I've taken the bravery to modify Your example code above to show You the problem; You can modify it back. Thanks.

Oh! My bad. Thanks for your patience. I finally got your point. You want this decorator to work with all function calls. The definition of 'work' means: 1. The decorator should correctly handle parameters for all types of functions (classmethod, staticmethod, instance method, standalone function, and even classmethod called by an instance). 2. The decorator should be able to directly decorate functions without needing to change the order of decorators. Is my understanding correct?

I think maybe using a class decorator with __call__ and __get__ could do the trick.

I think you are on a good approach,  and this is getting closer - the problem with this code is that __get__ is returning the decorated callable dirctly - so, __call__ on your LoggerDecorator class is never called (and never actually logs anything) .
It should rather take note of the owner and instance parameters, and return self, and __call__ should be the one retrieving the method from a class. It has to be done carefully so functions (in contrast with methods) will also work (__call__ is called directly in this case).

Wow, for now it seems to work, though I've yet to understand how __get__  is called and by whom. Many thanks.

On the other hand in my original decorator I have used the  __call__ for everything, now I'll have to figure out how the __get__ will give back the control to the __call__ if this is possible.

Hm, I made another slight modification, I set self.func to thet got function and return self.__call__, this way I always go through self.__call__ (thus log at one function) while everything seems to work -so far. Many thanks for all Your work, great learn.

Oooops! I found some more question, Lol. It seems that I don't have to check if not instance, it still works.

One more thing, since this logger must be parametrized :-D, I'm experimenting with adding parameters to it, like @LoggerDecorator(log_file_path=some_path) instead of just @LoggerDecorator. Such a challenge
